# Install PECL-Extension "SPL-Types" without server permissions

Tags: php, pecl

I want to use SPLEnum, a part of the PECL-Extension SPL-Types, in my Web Application.

Now, I've never worked with extensions, so I don't know how they are working. I've asked my hoster to install the package, but they could not because of security reasons on their servers.

Is it somehow possible to manually include files, just like in Java (manually copy the files to the webserver and include them)?

Thanks for your answers

Regards, Flo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PECL contains C extensions for compiling into PHP. Therefore you need the appropriate rights on the server running PHP, which you will never get on a shared hosting. Try to find a similar PEAR extension, these are written in PHP and behave like any other PHP file.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache rather than nginx. Using the script from [here](https://gist.github.com/jbenner55/9879908) works.

```
sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev php5-dev php-pear -y
sudo pecl install SPL_Types
echo extension=spl_types.so | sudo tee /etc/php5/mods-available/spl_types.ini
sudo php5enmod spl_types
sudo service apache2 reload
```

The key difference between this and Michael Noyb's answer is that this continues on to take care of loading the extension into Apache by using the php5enmod system, which you can [read about here](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2012/managing-php-5-4-extensions-on-ubuntu).

### Shared Hosting

CodeZombie's answer is spot on that a shared host will not let you do this, but you can spin up your own virtual private server (VPS) on something like [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) for $5 a month which is roughly the same cost of a shared hosting plan.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 14.04 using php5-fpm and nginx and php 5.5+

```
sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev
sudo apt-get install php5-dev
sudo pecl install SPL_Types
```

then go to `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` and add this line

```
extension=spl_types.so
```

Note: you may have to do the same for `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`

then

```
sudo service nginx restart
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

Then you can write classes like this (real life example for me):

```
<?php

namespace Metronic\Lib;

use SplEnum;
class PortletColor extends SplEnum {
    const __default = self::YELLOW;

    const YELLOW = 'yellow';
}
```

When you need to call the constant yellow, you use `\Metronic\Lib\PortletColor::YELLOW`;

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 12.04+ installation order:

```
sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev
sudo apt-get install php5-dev
sudo apt-get install php-pear
sudo pecl install SPL_Types
```